# PHP. Download image from php image generator

Tags: php, image, download, generator

Normally I download images from my php scripts using this code:

```
$imageurl='www.example.com/image.jpg'
$exten = substr($imageurl, -3);
$content = file_get_contents($imageurl);
$filename = './temp.'.$exten;
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

How can I download an image from a php image generator URL, for example http://www.example.net/getlampimage.php?id=151

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the content with an image MIME type, and then use GD to actually build the image.

This manual page has some examples of how to output images:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

And here's how to create a PHP image resource from a file:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know if i didn't explain myself well or if I don't understand your answer. I want to download an image from my provider. Normally my provider gives me a link like example.com/image.jpg, but this time he is giving a link like this: example.com/getimage.php?id=151 How can I download this image with my script??

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. It should be the exact same way as you did it, only get rid of the $exten variable and give the file whatever file name you think is right. If the MIME type is not uniform on that particular site, then you can use fileinfo to detect it and rename the file accordingly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php